# python 3 , Swampy , "import swampy.TurtleWorld" , "ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3 and I have installed python tkinter and Swampy.
When I type

```
import swampy.TurtleWorld
```

in python IDLE, it prints

> ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'

I have no idea about the reason. May someone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To use Swampy in **Python 3**, you need to install it in a specific way, detailed here: [Swampy Installation Instructions](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html) (page bottom).

Basically, you will have to download the source code as a zip file, unzip it and make sure that it is reachable by Python. Then you will be able to import TurtleWorld like this:

```
import TurtleWorld
```

Or you could just use **Python 2** for this project :)